# What is the correct way to make an Installed Build?

Tags: unreal-4

I am trying to use the Automation tool, following [the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Deployment/UsinganInstalledBuild/index.html).

> To create an Installed Build:
>
> Run the Installed Build Script by invoking the AutomationTool with the
> following command line, **replacing [PLATFORM] with either Win64 or Mac**.
>
> BuildGraph -target="Make Installed Build [PLATFORM]"
> -script=Engine/Build/InstalledEngineBuild.xml -clean

However, I am getting this error.

> `ERROR: Target 'Make Installed Build [Win64]' is not in graph`

I am not sure what I should put as the platform.

I searched the config file, but don't see any specified platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the brackets.

```
BuildGraph -target="Make Installed Build Win64" -script=Engine/Build/InstalledEngineBuild.xml -clean
```

That works.